# VHDL code for Tic Tac Toe

Tags: vhdl, fpga, tic-tac-toe

I'm making a simple tic tac toe game but there's problem.

Apparently, the "player" signal is never what I want it to be. I tried declaring it as boolean and initializing it as true, but it never entered the if clause; however, it didn't enter the clause when I changed it to false either. Then, I tried changing it to bit and yeah.. same problem

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity ticTacToe is
port(
    hex: OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(0 TO 6);
    useless         : out bit           := '1';
    win_X           : out bit           := '1';
    win_O           : out bit           := '1';
    row0line0_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row1line0_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row2line0_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row0line1_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row1line1_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row2line1_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row0line2_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row1line2_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U';
    row2line2_in    :   in  std_logic   := 'U'
);
end ticTacToe;


architecture behaviour of ticTacToe is
    signal player           : bit; --X starts game
    shared variable wins    : boolean   := false;

    shared variable row0line0   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row1line0   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row2line0   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row0line1   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row1line1   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row2line1   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row0line2   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row1line2   :   std_logic   := 'U';
    shared variable row2line2   :   std_logic   := 'U';


    function winner(row0line0, row0line1, row0line2, row1line0, row1line1,
        row1line2, row2line0, row2line1, row2line2:std_logic) return boolean is
    begin
        --check if X wins
        if(row0line0 = '1' and row0line1 = '1' and row0line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line0 = '1' and row1line0 = '1' and row2line0 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line0 = '1' and row1line1 = '1' and row2line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row1line0 = '1' and row1line1 = '1' and row1line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row2line0 = '1' and row2line1 = '1' and row2line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row2line0 = '1' and row1line1 = '1' and row0line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line1 = '1' and row1line1 = '1' and row2line1 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line2 = '1' and row1line2 = '1' and row2line2 = '1') then
            win_X <= '0';
        end if;

        --check if O wins
        if(row0line0 = '0' and row0line1 = '0' and row0line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line0 = '0' and row1line0 = '0' and row2line0 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line0 = '0' and row1line1 = '0' and row2line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row1line0 = '0' and row1line1 = '0' and row1line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row2line0 = '0' and row2line1 = '0' and row2line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row2line0 = '0' and row1line1 = '0' and row0line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line1 = '0' and row1line1 = '0' and row2line1 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;
        if(row0line2 = '0' and row1line2 = '0' and row2line2 = '0') then
            win_O <= '0';
        end if;

    return false;   
    end winner;

begin
    --variable becomes '0' for player O and '1' for player X
    process(row0line0_in, row0line1_in, row0line2_in, row1line0_in, row1line1_in,
        row1line2_in, row2line0_in, row2line1_in, row2line2_in)is
    begin
        if(row0line0_in'event and row0line0_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row0line0 := '1';
            else
                useless <= '0';
                row0line0 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row0line1_in'event and row0line1_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row0line1 := '1';
            else
                row0line1 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row0line2_in'event and row0line2_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row0line2 := '1';
            else
                row0line2 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row1line0_in'event and row1line0_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row1line0 := '1';
            else
                row1line0 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row1line1_in'event and row1line1_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row1line1 := '1';
            else
                row1line1 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row1line2_in'event and row1line2_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row1line2 := '1';
            else
                row1line2 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row2line0_in'event and row2line0_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row2line0 := '1';
            else
                row2line0 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row2line1_in'event and row2line1_in = '1')then
            if(player = '0')then
                row2line1 := '1';
            else
                row2line1 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;

        if(row2line2_in'event and row2line2_in = '1') then 
            if(player = '0')then
                row2line2 := '1';
            else
                row2line2 := '0';
            end if;
        end if;
        player <= not player;
    end process;

    --check winner
    process(player)is
    begin
        wins    :=  winner(row0line0, row0line1, row0line2, row1line0, row1line1,
        row1line2, row2line0, row2line1, row2line2);
    end process;
end behaviour;
```

If anyone has an idea of what the problem might be, I'd appreciate it!

Comment: If you were to look at [FPGA Tic Tac Toe](http://www.instructables.com/id/FPGA-Tic-Tac-Toe/) you'd find the game board is comprised of multi color LEDs, red for one player, green for the other. The implication that the game board has two bits for each position on the 3x3 grid. Note it uses a clock (and a reset). Also note it scores on the two diagonals.

Answer (score 2):

I see several major problems here.

1. Your design has no clock signal. It's attempting to edge-trigger on *all* of the inputs (e.g, `row0line0_in`), which is unlikely to synthesize to working logic.

   **You need a clock signal.** If this concept isn't familiar to you, it's time to go back to the books and read up on how sequential logic is designed.
2. Your design is attempting to use `'U'` as a value for `std_logic` signals. This value is only meaningful in simulation, where it's used to indicate an *uninitialized* value; in synthesis, these signals will all be initialized with an arbitrary value (probably 0). If you actually want to store three different values, you will need to use a multiple-bit type for that.
3. The expression `player <= not player` in your first process is not associated with any event. This will have unexpected behavior in simulation (the value will probably change whenever the value of any of the inputs changes, either from 0 to 1 or vice versa), and it will fail to synthesize at all (as there is no sensible way to trigger this logic on both edges of multiple clocks).

Answer (score 2):

All the issues pointed out in duskwuff's answer are correct and probably fix your problem. However, I would like to add a few issues of bad VHDL:

I highly recommend you stop using the `bit` type immediately. Use only `std_logic` if you want to express logic. The reasons can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/51848/when-to-use-std-logic-over-bit-in-vhdl). I would argue that 95% of the time(and definitely in your case), the same argument is also applicable to the usage of the `boolean` type.

Also, please do not use `shared variable`. This is VHDL. It's hardware description, not program code. VHDL does not define what happens when conflicting accesses of the variable happen. Shared variables in VHDL have very few and very specific use cases. You appear to be a beginner, so my advice would be: Forget the concept exists. It is not likely to yield good code or coding practices for you. Use only signals.

In your case, the variable declarations also happen to do absolutely nothing at all. Your function declaration contains the declarations of all the variables, and VHDL generally uses the most local declaration. Your architecture-global shared variables never get used. Only the `wins` variable is assigned, but it never gets assigned to an output or read back, so it also is useless. You should declare `wins` as `signal wins : std_logic` and remove the other shared variables.

Finally, a slightly more advanced aspect. You are very keen on initializing your inputs, outputs, signals and variables. Maybe that's because you have learnt to do so as a coder, maybe that's because you read somewhere you should. Be aware however, that these initializations are not guaranteed to be synthesizable. On an ASIC or on a flash-based FPGA that does not load a configuration bitstream from ROM, most likely those initializations do not work. This can and will lead to funky undefined behaviour, where one chip of a batch will reliably initialize to 0 at room temperature where another will reliably initialize to 1(I have seen this happen with Microsemi FPGAs). If you do as duskwuff recommends and initialize to `'1'` or `'0'`, you run the risk of simulation mismatch(i.e. your simulations with these initializations work differently than your actual hardware). 
Consider not initializing your signals at declaration and rather initializing them on reset. This way, you will see the state `U` in your simulator if you forget to reset a signal and know something is wrong.

Comment: I agree with your 3 last recommendations but not with the first one. Do **not** use `std_logic` instead of `bit`. Using resolved types when they are not needed is very bad practice and error prone. Use `std_ulogic` if you really don't want to use `bit`. And `boolean` is absolutely fine to express conditions. VHDL is a **high** level language. Do not follow advices that bring you back to low level programming without any reason.

Comment: I mostly disagree. First: I think you are right, `std_ulogic` is arguably the better and less error-prone choice. The only reason I use `std_logic` is habit and the thought that in practice, errors because of resolution rarely happen to me because I'm careful with my signals - which isn't a very good point at all. **BUT**, if you agree with my last point about initialization, you cannot also state that `bit` is a good type to use. `bit` signals are always initialized and you have **no way** to find a forgotten initialization because you used `bit`. This is a real problem.